# Proper way of getting route parameters globally?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

This is working code as of Angular 2.4.8:

```
constructor(private _router:Router) {
  _router.events
  .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd) 
  .forEach(e => {
    console.log(_router.routerState.root.firstChild.params['valu‌​e']['id']);
    console.log(_router.routerState.root.firstChild.firstChild.p‌​arams['value']['id']‌​);
  );
}
```

I have a hard time believing this is the way to do this, because when I used dot syntax, like:

```
_router.routerState.root.firstChild.p‌​arams.value;
```

or

```
_router.routerState.root.firstChild.firstChild.p‌​arams.value;
```

...I get:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Observable<Params>'.
```

It feels hacky, but for now the above code works. I was just wondering about the proper way to get route parameters.

Comment: Are you sure your code doesn't contain a typo? You inject `_router` and then you use `router`. What is strange is that `router.events` should contain an observable and you should not be able to use a method like `forEach()` on it.